# Unity constructor injection with other parameter

Tags: c#, oop, unity-container

I have a class with a constructor that looks like the following:

```
public BatchService(IRepository repository, ILogger logger, string user)
```

In my DI bootstrapper class, I have the following `RegisterType` command:

```
.RegisterType<BatchService>(
    new InjectionConstructor(
        new ResolvedParameter<IRepository>("SomeRepository"), 
        new ResolvedParameter<ILogger>("DatabaseLogger")))
```

In my client code, I want to instantiate `BatchService` as follows:

```
BatchService batchService = DIContainer.Resolve<BatchService>()
```

As you can see, I have a string parameter called `user` as part of the constructor to `BatchService` that is not part of the DI logic.  How should I best handle this situation if I need to use `user` in the `BatchService` class?

Answer (score 7):

You can use `ParameterOverride`:

```
BatchService batchService = 
DIContainer.Resolve<BatchService>(new ParameterOverride("user", valueForUser));
```

Answer (score 7):

Please don't [abuse Unity as a ServiceLocator](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx).

If you want to create objects that need runtime parameters use a factory. You can even drop the act of implementing that factory by either using the Unity version of [Typed Factories](http://outlawtrail.wordpress.com/2012/07/27/auto-generated-factories-with-unity/) or [let Unity generate factory delegates](http://outlawtrail.wordpress.com/2012/07/27/generate-strongly-typed-factory-delegates/) for you.

Comment: This is the only comment that guides to the correct usage rather than just answer the OP's question

Comment: Good answer.  Does the linked article require some third party library called "TecX"?  It's unclear whether the code there works out of the box with Unity or not.

Comment: @JoshNoe `TypedFactories` are not part of Unity. TecX is not really a library but an assortment of solutions to various problems that came up at some point. But it's OS so you can grab any part of the code an use it as you like.

Comment: @SebastianWeber would be grateful if you could explain how you would do this with a factory manually, without using Typed Factories or Factory Delegates. I'm trying to do a similar thing myself but think i am slightly off track http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28073920/c-sharp-dependency-injection-passing-additional-paramater?noredirect=1#comment44529027_28073920

Comment: This answer addresses tangential topic of this question and misses the actual problem.

Answer (score -1):

First of all it's not good idea mix `ILogger` with business logic. You can create ILogger directly in `BatchService` or resolve thru `[Dependency]` attribute. DI it's not panacea, business object creation shouldn't depend from `ILogger`

Use `new InjectionParameter<string>("user")` Take a look please [Registering Injected Parameter and Property Values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660882%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx) for more details