# C# Dependency Injection passing additional parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, unity-container, factory

I have a class similar to the following:

```
public class CarAttributes
{
   private readonly ICarRepository _carRepository;
   private readonly int _carId;

   public CarAttributes(ICarRepository carRepository, int carId)
   {
      _carRepository = carRepository;
      _carId = carId;
   }

   public bool IsRegistered
   {
      get
      {
          return _carRepository.IsRegistered(_carId);
      }
   }

   public bool IsStolen
   {
      get
      {
         return _carRepository.IsStolen(_carId);
      }
   }
}
```

I also have the following method (which is syntactically incorrect)

```
public CarAttributes GetCarAttributes(int carId)
{
    return new CarAttributes(carId);
}
```

I am using Unity to inject the ICarRepository at runtime

```
container.RegisterType<ICarRepository, CarRepository>();
```

How do I inject CarAttributes with the CarRepository via Unity but allow the program to supply the carId?

Am I correct in thinking that i need a factory to do this?

Something perhaps like the following

```
public class CarAttributesFactory()
{
   private readonly ICarRepository _carRepository;
   public CarAttributesFactory(ICarRepository carRepository)
   {
      _carRepository = carRepository;
   }

   public CarAttributes GetCarAttributes(int carId)
   {
      return new CarAttributes(_carRepository, carId);
   }
}
```

This allows unity to inject the factory with the dependency, but will also allow the program to specify the carId when the GetCarAttributes method is invoked.

However is this not going against the DI principles, as I am creating a dependency here between the CarAttributesFactory and the CarAttributes classes.

Is this the correct usage for using factories?

Also I have read about other DI frameworks having things such as TypedFactories for this kind of thing, although I would like to do it manually first to understand the concepts.

Here for example
[Unity - Constructor Injection with other parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994952/unity-constructor-injection-with-other-parameter)

Hope this makes sense.

EDIT: Example usage

From my MVC controller I need to be able to retrieve back a CarAttributes object for a specific carId which will be passed in via a view model. The CarAttributes class requires the use of one or more repositories (only one shown in this example), as well as a run time parameter passed in which is carId depending on what comes though the view model.

(I would also have to create an ICarAttributesFactory interface as well in order to inject the factory into the controller in the below example)

```
public SomeController : Controller
{
   private readonly ICarAttributesFactory _carAttributesFactory;

   public SomeController(ICarAttributesFactory carAttributesFactory)
   {
      _carAttributesFactory = carAttributesFactory;
   }

   public ActionResult Submit(DataViewModel model)
   {
       // model will contain a carId property
       var carAttribs = _carAttributesFactory.GetCarAttributes(model.carId);

      if(carAttribs.IsStolen)
      {
           // do something 
      }
   }

}
```

Comment: What's missing from your question is what the intended usage of the `CarAttributes` is. Can you update your question and show some example code of how you are intended to use this `CarAttributes`?

Comment: @Steven I have added further info, hope it's clear as I'm starting to question my own direction now.

Comment: Does IsRegistered and IsStolen need to be properties?

Comment: @TTat that is a good question, I suppose they could be fields on the object populated in the constructor, still to construct the object it would need the ICarRepository and the carId.

Comment: Specifically, can they be methods?  That way when you use it, you can pass the carId into IsStolen() and IsRegistered().

Comment: @TTat There could possibly be 15 attributes, I don't want to manually call each one. I want to be able to say, get me a CarAttributes object for this carId please and have a pre-constructed object with all the properties set given back to me.

Comment: Then short answer, yes a factory is your best option.  With the factory returning ICarAttributes.

Comment: Is it ok for the factory to use the new keyword then, as that is creating a dependancy on CarAttributes then ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69340/discussion-between-general-exception-and-ttat).

Comment: Right now each call to one of the properties of your `CarAttributes` class results in a call to your repository which translates to a call to your persistent storage. That usually means a serious performance impact. Wouldn't it make more sense to load the object from storage in one go like `_carRepository.GetAttributesById(carId)`? Then you could skip the factory altogether.

Comment: @SebastianWeber ok fine i could change the properties to fields, but the same issue still applies, how do I inject carId into the constructor along with the ICarRepository ? The reason i need to combine them into a single object is that the two methods in the ICarRepository go to completely different areas of the system, for example IsStolen() may be a database query whereas IsRegistered() may be a SOAP call.