# Unity constructor injection as a runtime parameter

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I am building a Web API (Repository Pattern) with Unity as a DI container.

My service is consuming a repository which accepts logged-in userid as a parameter.
This user-id parameter should be coming from header of http request.

My Repository:

```
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    private readonly UserInformationObj _userInformation;

    public UserRepository(Guid currentUserId)
    {       
        _userInformation = LoadUserData(currentUserId.ToString());
    }
}
```

Unity configuration:

```
container.RegisterType<IUserRepository, UserRepository>(new InjectionConstructor(Guid.Empty));
```

How would I get the value from HTTP Header in unity?

Not sure if this is similar https://stackoverflow.com/a/11995346/1169180. I did not understand the solution. Could anyone quickly guide me what exactly needs to be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The point is that you have two phases with `unity-container`, registration and resolution. Since you don't know the value of the `Guid` during the registration you should remove `InjectionConstructor` from the registration.

```
container.RegisterType<UserRepository>();
```

On the other hand, you do know the `Guid` during the resolution, it comes from the request. So the idea is to resolve the `IUserRepository` and inject the `Guid` there. That means that with each request you will resolve a new instance of the repository and inject the value of the `Guid` into it...

```
guid = Guid.Parse(request.Headers["CurrentUserId"])
var rep = _container.Resolve<UserRepository>(new ParameterOverride("currentUserId", guid));
```

Comment: @Shaggy you are not accessing it from unity but from your request handler, there you should inject `IUnityContainer` and resolve repository with each request... Understand?

Comment: I would like to do resolution thing in Unity only, as I have many other repositories/service which is using `UserRepository`. As per my understanding for each request unity will resolve the instance and initialize the repository with the current user id. Any way to do that?

Comment: Generally speaking, that magic doesn't exist as you somehow have to provide that `Guid`. There is also an option to provide id through the methods of the `IUserRepository` than you can rid of this?

Comment: I didn't get the last part of your comment. Could you explain with some code?

Comment: @Shaggy What are the signatures of the methods `UserRepository`? Why do you need to provide userId through ctor but not methods?